# tikz: printing fixed format number on axis

Tags: latex, tikz

I would like to print fixed format number on the axis. However, tikz always prints the decimal (.10^⁻2) on top (see below picture), even if I set

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}
```

[image]

The header of the image is

```
\begin{axis}[
   ylabel={$\dfrac{u}{h \varepsilon \bar{R}^4}$},
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.15,.4)},anchor=south,rotate=-90},
   grid=major,
   legend entries={iga-p=3-q=3,analytical},
   legend style={at={(0.7,0.6)},anchor=south west},
   ymin=0,
   ymax=0.08,
   xmin=0,
   xmax=10,
   ytick={0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08}
 ]
```

What could be done to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `scaled ticks=false`solved the problem.